# How to do the thing described below

Tags: android

I have `act1.xml` and `act2.xml`. I have 2 java class files as java1 and java2. I wrote methods in java1 such as share ,capture whose activity is act1 is working fine .I just want to use those onClick method in java2 whose activity is act2.xml.

```
 public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
 final static int CAMERA_RESULT = 0;
 ImageView imv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    // Get position from intent passed from MainActivity.java
    Intent i = getIntent();

    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    // Open the Image adapter
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Get image and position from ImageAdapter.java and set into ImageView
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);


    i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
        }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent       intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}
```

Method I want to reuse.

```
       btntakephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            File photostorage =    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            photofile = new File(photostorage, (System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");


            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); //intent to start camera
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photofile));
            startActivityForResult(i, TAKENPHOTO);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What image? You should post some code instead, so people can copy and paste it into their editors.

Comment: unable to post the image....

Comment: You want to re-use code in your java1 class?

Comment: yes...this is my java2 class.I want my method of java1 to be to be reuse here...

Comment: If what you want is to have 2 different classes using the same method, you could make a static method and call them directly. If what you want is have the same method run in2 different places, create an object in each place and call the method there.

Comment: Define a static method which contains the body of activity1's onClick method. Then call it on both activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class as of below:

```
public class ClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Then in your activity1 & activity 2, use setOnClickListener like this:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.act1_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler());

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.act2_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler());
```

Comment: thanks.. for the help....its crashing   but at least the buttons start responding..

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use `firstActivity.class` `OnClick` method to use some method of `SecondActivity.class`, then you can use `BroadcastManager`.

But if you want to pass some data from `FirstActivity.java` to `SecondActivity.java`, then simply use `Intent` and `Bundle`.

Comment: I think , you want to get a image in first activity, and want to send this image to 2nd file

Comment: No,...actually I am getting an image from gridview and showing it in background...and at the same time I am trying to capture image from camera and save it.So I just need to reuse my code here.I am able to capture picture but save button is not working in this activity.How to call that method of java1.class to the above code.